# Escaping double quoted column names with VectorAssembler in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Working on implementing a basic credit card fraud detection algorithm on data which I downloaded from Kaggle.

The column names seem to be double quoted like so: "Time","V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12","V13","V14","V15","V16","V17","V18","V19","V20","V21","V22"....

What I'm trying to do is use VectorAssembler to combine all columns to a feature column for MLlib like so:

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["Time","V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12","V13","V14","V15","V16","V17","V18","V19","V20","V21","V22","V23","V24","V25","V26","V27","V28","Amount"],
    outputCol="features")

output = assembler.transform(df)
```

But get the error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "Time" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: "Time","V1","V2","V3","
```

I realize this is due to double quoted column names, since I tried changing a single column name using:

```
 df1 = df.selectExpr("""'Time' as test""")
```

Which then worked. However, doesn't seem like a good solution to "hardcode" the select on all columns, given that in this example I have 30, and in the next I might have even more.

I tried every possible syntax, i.e.:

```
 inputCols=['"Time"']
 inputCols=["'Time'"]
 inputCols=[""Time""]
 inputCols=["""Time"""]
 inputCols=["´Time´"]
```

But all give the same error. Is there any solution to this or should I just hardcode the select statement to rename the columns?

Comment: strip the double-quotes in column names: `df = df.toDF(*[ c.strip('"') for c in df.columns ])`

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked, ignore my last comment.